# changing source code(client side) and end users

Tags: javascript, client-side, end-user

What will happen to the users who are already on the site if the source codes are being changed while they are on?

My website is already live and there are already users on the site, but there are still changes that needs to be made, how will these users be affected if I change parts of the javascript, such as adding new buttons to click on and new formatting..etc

Comment: they need to refresh the page in order to see the new things

Answer (score 1):

If I view a page and then you save a new version of it then nothing changes for me until I do something that causes that page to be reloaded.

On a very simple page this just means that the layout of the page changes the next time I visit it. If there is any simple interaction using javascript, then as long as that doesn't need any information from the server it will continue working as it did before you changed it.

The only time there'll be an issue is if the page needs any information from the server (either via form posts or ajax calls) and the structure of the data doesn't match because of one of your changes. This will be broken until I reload the page to receive the new version that expects the new data formats.